# How to download receipt in PDF format in mobile using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, I am building a mobile app with angular and JavaScript. I want to print a receipt in my app. So i want to download receipt in PDF format. I searched and do not get a working code. The receipt is in table tag.
My code is here.

```
<div id="preview" class="container">
        <h4 class="h4-order">Order Date <span>{{order_time|date:'mediumDate'}}</span></h4>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><b>Qty</b></th>
                <th><b>Product</b></th>
                <th><b>From</b></th>
                <th><b>Price</b></th>
                <th><b>Offer</b></th>
                <th><b>Total</b></th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="receipt in new_receipts">
                <td>{{receipt.quantity}}</td>
                <td>{{receipt.name}}</td>
                <td>{{receipt.ownname}}</td>
                <td>{{receipt.price}}</td>
                <td ng-if="receipt.offer">{{receipt.offer}}%</td>
                <td ng-if="!receipt.offer">0%</td>
                <td>{{receipt.total}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="receipt-total">
            <h3>Sub Total : <span><img src="img/mybag/rs.png" class="rs-mybag-total"/> {{total}}</span></h3>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Are you looking to take a snap shot and then download as a pdf?

Comment: I need only a particular div to save as PDF. The div having id 'preview'

Comment: I don't think javascript can do this. could `window.print()` be what you're looking for?

Comment: I tried it but it works only in desktop browser, not working in mobile

Comment: Can i take the screenshot of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using

> cordova.plugins.printer

I got the PDFto print the receipt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf) library:

```
var element = document.getElementById('preview');
html2pdf(element);
```

Or, if you prefer a bit more of control, you can use directly [js2PDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) (which html2pdf uses as base library)

Comment: Its showing "TypeError: html2pdf is not a function"

Comment: can anyone share working code for converting html to pdf in mobile devices?